# .net core 3.0 Auto migration does not create/update/ datatable automatically

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am building a project template using .net core 3.0 and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.
this will just created the database schema not the data table

```
if (!context.Database.EnsureCreated())
    context.Database.Migrate();
```

Do we have an automatic migration that helps to create/update datatable without needing to manually call
Add-Migration
Update database

I was able to build it automatically in .net using Code base EF6, it will just detect if you have created a new field in the model and add it to database automatically.

Do we have something in .net Core ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do we have an automatic migration that helps to create/update datatable without needing to manually call Add-Migration Update database

As far as I know, [automatic migration feature has been removed in EF Core](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6214#issuecomment-239519498).

And [`DbContext.Database.Migrate();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.migrate?view=efcore-3.1) just help apply any pending migrations for the context to the database, which mean that we should created migration(s) first otherwise it would not work.